# How to update particular column of all rows using spring data mongo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have Tenant table where only one tenant should be active at a time.

To activate a tenant i am using following code. Is there a better way to change particular column of all rows using spring data mongo.

```
        tenantRepository.save(tenantRepository.findAll().stream().map(t -> {
            t.setActive(false);
            return t;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        tenant.setActive(true);
        tenantRepository.save(tenant);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Spring Data Mongo update only dirty field in a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397833/can-spring-data-mongo-update-only-dirty-field-in-a-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update specific column(s) in Spring data Mongo, simply define your custom repository interface and its implementation like:

### Define Custom Interface

```
public interface TenantRepositoryCustom {

    Integer updateStatus(List<String> id, TenantStatus status, Date date);
}
```

### Implement your Custom Interface

```
@Repository
public class TenantRepositoryCustomImpl implements TenantRepositoryCustom{

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate template;

    @Override
    Integer updateStatus(List<String> id, TenantStatus status, Date date) {
        WriteResult result = template.updateMulti(new Query(Criteria.where("id").in(ids)),
                new Update().set("status", status).set("sentTime", date), Tenant.class);
        return result.getN();
    }
```

### Extends you Default Tenant Repository from Custom Repository:

```
public interface TenantRepository extends MongoRepository<Tenant, String>, TenantRepositoryCustom{
}
```

### Use Custom repository in Service

```
    @Service
    public class TenantService{
        @Autowired
        TenantRepository repo;

        public void updateList(){
            //repo.updateStatus(...)
        }
   }
```

### Note:

This is less error prone as compared to using @Query, as here you will have to just specify column's names and values instead of complete query.