# How to sync retrieved entity data with edited data from backend in hibernate.?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

One recruiter asked me the below question, can someone answer this? I think versioning concept won't work here.

In Hibernate, at 11.10am, my application retrieved a record from the database. Before this record gets committed, i update the record in the database via sql client. Now when my application try to update, the record should contain both updates (done from sql client and application updates). How do you do that?

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674516/hibernate-dirty-checking-and-only-update-of-dirty-attributes

Comment: No, it is entirely different. They are talking about dynamic insert and update. My question is different.